# Is it possible to ignore all validation rules of a property?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI validation issue. Let me explain the scenario:

This is the model

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    public bool CustomizationEnabled { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

All validation filters on **Name** property should be applied only if **CustomizationEnabled = True**.

I have two approaches for this requirement

1. Remove all validation filters on **Name**, and apply a custom validation logic in the api controller. It looks easy but code reusable is an issue.
2. Create a attribute such as **IgnoreIfFalse** and some how ask WebAPI to ignore configured filters: [MaxLength(255)] + [MinLength(2)]..., but I don't have any idea if this approach is doable.

The IgnoreIfFailse attribute may have a property to hold which property to be checked (here is CustomizationEnabled).

How do you think of these approaches? I would highly appreciate any suggestion. Tks

Comment: what is the usecase?

Comment: @Guanxi, thanks for your interest. The UC is user goes to profile page, he can click on a checkbox (CustomizationEnabled  = true), then a panel is shown allow he update his profile with detail pages. Otherwise those information is taken from external provider.

Comment: I would keep two separate models.

Comment: This is nice @Guanxi, I have similar though also. It requires to create a different action with the same http method POST, use a different route (can use Route attribute / Action Name), but there will be an issue with transactional, two methods will issue two transactions.